# Разное поведение программы на Win7 и WinXP

Tags: c++, windows, многопоточность, winapi

Есть такой код (минимальный рабочий пример):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdint>

HDC hDC; 
HDC  hDCMem;
HBITMAP hbitmap;
HWND  hwnd; 
int ScreenMaxX;
int ScreenMaxY;

short pattern[8]={~0xFF, ~0xFF, ~0xFF, ~0xFF, ~0xFF, ~0xFF, ~0xFF, ~0xFF};
HBRUSH brush=::CreatePatternBrush(::CreateBitmap(8, 8, 1, 1, pattern));

void bar(int nLeft, int nTop, int nRight, int nBottom)
{
    RECT rect;
    rect.left   = nLeft;
    rect.right  = nRight;
    rect.top    = nTop;
    rect.bottom = nBottom;

    ::SetTextColor(hDCMem, 0xFF00FF);
    ::SetBkColor(hDCMem, 0xFF00FF);
    //brush=::CreatePatternBrush(::CreateBitmap(8, 8, 1, 1, pattern));
    ::FillRect(hDCMem, &rect, brush);
}

void flush(){
    ::BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, ScreenMaxX, ScreenMaxY, hDCMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
}

CRITICAL_SECTION graphics_cs;

uint8_t thread_cnt=0;
uint8_t total_threads=2;
HANDLE turnstile1=CreateSemaphoreW(nullptr, 0, 2, nullptr);

void thread_func(int num){
    int x,y;
    if(num==0){
        x=20; y=0;
    } else {
        x=110; y=0;
    }

    while(true) {
        while(true) {
            EnterCriticalSection(&graphics_cs);
            if (thread_cnt == num) {
                thread_cnt++;
                bar(x, y, x+40, y+40);
                y+=1;
                //flush();
                if(thread_cnt==total_threads){
                    thread_cnt = 0;
                    flush();
                    ReleaseSemaphore(turnstile1, total_threads, nullptr);
                }
                LeaveCriticalSection(&graphics_cs);
                break;
            } else {
                LeaveCriticalSection(&graphics_cs);
            }
        }

        WaitForSingleObject(turnstile1, INFINITE);

        Sleep(100);
    }
}

void mainx ()
{
    InitializeCriticalSection(&graphics_cs);
    for(int i=0; i<total_threads; i++){
        CreateThread (nullptr, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)thread_func, (LPVOID)i, 0, nullptr);
    }
}

DWORD Th(LPVOID param) // новая нить
{
    (void)param;
    ::SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOP,  // дескриптор окна и порядок размещения
                   10,   // позиция по-горизонтали
                   10,  // по-вертикали
                   400,  // ширина
                   500,  // высота
                   SWP_SHOWWINDOW  // отобразить
    );
    mainx();
    flush();
    return 0;
}
DWORD g_nMainThreadID;

//обработка сообщений главного окна приложения
long FAR PASCAL WindowProc(HWND   hWnd,UINT   message, WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam )
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_PAINT:   flush();
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY: PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

int PASCAL WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR  lpCmdLine,  int  nShowCmd )
{
    (void)hPrevInstance, (void)lpCmdLine;
    WNDCLASS  wc;
    MSG       msg;

    wc.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = NULL;
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = "Menu_one";
    wc.lpszClassName = "NAME";

    if (!RegisterClass(&wc)) {return 0; };


    //создаем главное окно приложения
    hwnd = CreateWindow("NAME",               // имя класса окна
                        "!",                // заголовок окна
                        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,  // стиль окна
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,        //р-ры и расположение по-умолчанию
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,
                        HWND_DESKTOP,          // идентификатор родительского окна
                        NULL,                  // идентификатор меню
                        hInstance,             // идентификатор приложения
                        NULL                   // доп параметры
    );
    ScreenMaxX = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    ScreenMaxY = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    hDC = ::GetDC(hwnd);
    hDCMem  = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
    hbitmap = ::CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, ScreenMaxX, ScreenMaxY );
    ::SelectObject(hDCMem, hbitmap);
    auto hbrush = (HBRUSH)::GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    ::SelectObject(hDCMem, hbrush);
    ::PatBlt(hDCMem, 0,0, ScreenMaxX, ScreenMaxY, PATCOPY );
    ::DeleteObject(hbrush);
    

    CreateThread(NULL,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Th, (LPVOID)hwnd, 0,&g_nMainThreadID);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nShowCmd);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    // Запускаем цикл обработки сообщений
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Этот код медленно рисует две розовые полосы сверху вниз в разных потоках (потоку соответствует функция `thread_func`). Причём на Windows 7 полосы рисуются равномерно, а на Windows XP — с разной скоростью.

[image: пример работы]

(На Windows 7 левая полоса движется с той же скоростью, что и правая)

Я обнаружил, что если раскомментировать хотя бы одну из закомментированных строк с кодом, то поведение будет одинаковым. Почему поведение программы различается и почему при раскомментировании указанных строк она работает одинаково на разных ОС?

Comment: Были же ответы к этому вопросу? Или я что-то путаю?

Comment: @insolor нет, был один комментарий, но автор его удалил.

Comment: Интересный вопрос! Попробую разобраться, хотя придется повозиться с эмуляторами (не помню, есть ли у меня рабочие образы XP и 7-ки).

Да, на Windows 10 этот код работает одинаково, что с комментариями, что без.

P.S. Компилировать так (для VS из developer command prompt): **cl testdraw.cpp user32.lib gdi32.lib**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как написано, в ответе @SeNS, причина различия скоростей в том, что прямоугольники отрисовываются после 18 вызовов `FillRect`. Однако это не ошибка, а, в принципе, документированное поведение.

Данный механизм называется «пакетирование» (batching). Оказывается, если вызывать одну и ту же GDI функцию несколько раз в одном и том же потоке, то эти вызовы накапливаются в пакете (в каждом потоке создаётся свой пакет). И пока либо не вызовется другая GDI функция, либо размер пакета не превысит указанный максимальный размер (который возвращает функция `GdiGetBatchLimit`), либо не заполнится буфер пакетирования, отрисовки не происходит. В моём случае выполняется третье условие, так как максимальный размер пакета в моей системе равен 20-ти, а прямоугольник появляется после 18-го вызова.

Поэтому решением проблемы может быть, например, вызов функции `GdiFlush` после `FillRect`. Из названия понятно, что эта функция производит выполнение функций в пакете и его очистку. Но, на мой взгляд, в моей программе намного лучше вообще отключить пакетирование: `GdiSetBatchLimit(1)` в начале кода потока, так как всегда рисуется только один прямоугольник и сразу же выводится на экран.

Почему на некоторых Windows 7 пакетирование не работает, несмотря на то, что размер пакета также равен 20-ти, мне всё ещё не ясно. Возможно, дело в более новом менеджере рабочего стола, который как-то более хитро производит отрисовку. Также, не совсем очевидно, какие функции могут попасть в пакет, например, `Ellipse` срабатывает сразу.

Answer (score 4):

Повозился немного с кодом: похоже, что у Windows XP для memory DC работает какой-то хитрый механизм кэширования при выводе через `FillRect`, который изменен в последующих версиях Windows.

Например, если `void bar(..)` изменить подобным образом (т.е. для первого треда использовать `::Rectange` вместо `::FillRect`)

```
void bar(int num, int nLeft, int nTop, int nRight, int nBottom)
{
    RECT rect;
    rect.left   = nLeft;
    rect.right  = nRight;
    rect.top    = nTop;
    rect.bottom = nBottom;
    if (num == 0) {
       ::Rectangle(hDCMem, nLeft, nTop, nRight, nBottom);
    }
    else {
       ::SetTextColor(hDCMem, 0xFF00FF);
       ::SetBkColor  (hDCMem, 0xFF00FF);
       ::FillRect    (hDCMem, &rect, brush);
   }
}
```

то вывод будет идти параллельно.

Мои предположения (не уверен, что потянут на полноценный ответ, но все-же):

- `//brush=::CreatePatternBrush(::CreateBitmap(8, 8, 1, 1, pattern));` - практически любая функция, отличная от `::FillRect`, вызывает "сброс" кэширования и фактическое копирование в memory DC данных;
- `//flush();` - ну, это понятно, `::BitBlt` безусловно копирует содержимое memory DC в контекст устройства (т.е. физически "рисует"), заодно сбрасывая (перед рисованием) непонятное кэширование `::FillRect`.

Кстати, если добавить 
`::BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, ScreenMaxX, ScreenMaxY, hDCMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);` последним вызовом в процедуру `void bar(..)`, то рисование также будет идти одновременно на XP.

Без исходников точнее ответить сложно; вроде бы, в сети пролетали сорцы XP, но я сходу не нашел. Еще можно было-бы попробовать эту программку в React OS...

**[UPDATE]** По результатам дискуссии в комментариях (см. ниже), мы с автором вопроса пришли к выводу, что, скорее всего, такое поведение объясняется особенностями (или, скорее всего, ошибкой) реализации функции FillRect в GDI Windows XP. Скорее всего, в качестве "трика", повышающего быстродействие, используется внутреннее кэширование заполняемых областей (up to 18 вызовов), до фактической отрисовки в совместимый контекст устройства в памяти.
Сказать что-то точнее, без исходных кодов библиотеки GDI32, не представляется возможным.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Интересное предположение насчёт кэширования. К сожалению, сам я, действительно, не знаю правильного ответа. Что-то не соображу: если добавить вызов `BitBlt` в конец `bar` — разве это не то же самое, что раскомментированный `flush`?

Comment: И ещё такой момент: вы пишете, что `flush` сбрасывает кэширование, но ведь он и так вызывается. Если, например, добавить вывод в консоль после незакомментированного `flush` и поставить в `Sleep` задержку не 100, а 1000, то у меня он вызывается где-то 18 раз, и только потом появляется левая полоса. Как это объяснить?

Comment: Да, про 18 раз я тоже заметил, даже вот так код модифицировал для этого:
`void bar(int num, int nLeft, int nTop, int nRight, int nBottom){
     RECT rect;
    rect.left   = nLeft;
    rect.right  = nRight;
    rect.top    = nTop;
    rect.bottom = nBottom;

 if (num == 0)::SetTextColor(hDCMem, nTop % 18 == 0 ? 0x00FF00 : 0xFF00FF);
 else  ::SetTextColor(hDCMem, nTop % 18 == 0 ? 0x0000FF : 0xFFFF00);

 ::FillRect(hDCMem, &rect, brush);
}`
P.S. Сорри, не дает в комментах красиво расположить :(

Comment: На счёт вызова flush(): как я понял, идея такова, что мы рисуем в memDC много раз (тредов можно много сделать), а выводим на дисплей только один, т.е. используем технику double buffering. Я имел ввиду, что если выводить на hDC через ::BitBlt каждый раз после ::FillRect, то все работает (т.е. можно flush() убрать), но тогда не будет double buffering :) 
Из за бага/фичи GDI на XP каким-то образом (неправильным, видимо) кэширует растровые операции именно через ::FillRect (возможно, копит результат во внутреннем буфере - черт его знает!)

Comment: Я пробовал для первого треда (вообще, запускал 6 тредов, посде небольшой модификации кода) использовать другие GDI функции рисования - все отрабатывает, как должно.

Вообще, код GDI старинная и странная штука. Лет 6-7 назад я случайно наткнулся на код, который просто ... перегружал компьютер, даже без "синего экрана" (сразу падало в BIOS) простым вызовом стандартной GDI функции с ошибочными параметрами из user space! Падали все (на тот момент) операционки MS, включая XP, Vista и server 2010! Если интересно, могу показать.

P.S. Заняло пол-года убедить MS пофиксить этот баг!

Comment: Да, это тоже, видимо, баг, правда, не такой критичный. Я думаю, `FillRect` не выводит никуда данные, пока в потоке, в котором эта функция вызывается (а не в каком-либо другом), не сработает какая-нибудь другая GDI функция, ну или `flush` в другом не вызовется 18 раз. Если написать наоборот: `if(thread_cnt==1){flush();}`, то правильно рисуется левая полоса.

Comment: Точнее, не `flush` вызовется 18 раз, а сама функция `FillRect`. Это кстати справедливо и для вывода сразу в `hDC` (только я не знаю, можно ли так делать)

Comment: не могли бы вы изменить ответ, добавив информацию из комментариев?

Answer (score -1):

Вам просто повезло с текущим состоянием Windows 7. Грубо говоря, в вашем примере треды не обязаны работать синхронно, так как синхронизиации, кроме внутреннего счётчика нет.

Comment: Не могли бы вы подтвердить ваши слова конкретным примером неправильной работы потоков? Вообще тут не один счётчик — ещё критическая секция и семафор. И я тестировал на Win 7 несколько раз (и ещё @SeNS на Win 10).

Comment: Подтверждаю, потоки тут абсолютно не при чем! Можно, конечно, сделать намного проще, но в вопросе дело вовсе не в потоках!